# Large loss of files

Tags: apt

Here is the situation. I was playing with wine settings to see I could get to play some old games. Long story short I ended up removing wine. Right after my wife asked me to help her with something.
Along comes my beautiful and perfect daughter. I like, a fool did not close terminal. So with a combination of wild key presses she managed to enter the following command:

sudo apt-get remove wine*

Holy crap! This removed like 3/4ths of my installed programs. I am not a expert user but I know enough not to play with *.

At this point I'm about 80% sure I'm going to have to a fresh install. Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check out your apt-history, and (manually, I'm afraid) undo what has happend.

Check out `/var/log/apt/history.log` for that ([from serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/380856/how-to-undo-apt-get-remove)).

You could get pretty far with that as apt resolves a lot for you (if you do it the 'wrong way around' it fixes dependencies, so it might work well, but it will not fix your settings out of the box (the way you might expect "hmm, I just found this protocol/program/whatever that works with this program, lets just set it up for you") ... You might end up with some sort of frankenbox.

My advice would be: just try it quickly. If it looks like there wasn't too much uninstalled, you might luck out, but expect to be doing a fresh install.